# Python и допустимые значения для time.sleep

Tags: python, многопоточность

Есть один вопрос. В моей программе на Python работает множество потоков (может работать порядка тысячи). Каждый поток должен иногда на какое-то время засыпать. И это время может быть очень большим, иногда - час, иногда и вовсе сутки. Читая про time.sleep, наткнулся на рекомендации не "усыплять" поток на слишком большое время одним time.sleep. Например, чтобы "безопасно" усыпить поток на 1 час, нужно делать, как я понял, примерно следующее:

```
for i in range(1,60):
  time.sleep(60)
```

Я хотел уточнить, насколько такие рекомендации полезны, не напутали ли что-то люди. Однако информации по этому поводу мало. Может, кто нибудь знает про эту фичу?

Answer (score 2):

В исходном коде Python нет ограничений на размер времени которое программа будет спать. Но есть такое [замечание](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.sleep):

> The actual suspension time may be less than that requested because any caught signal will terminate the sleep() following execution of that signal’s catching routine. Also, the suspension time may be longer than requested by an arbitrary amount because of the scheduling of other activity in the system.

В целом эта цитата говорит, что время ожидания программы может отличаться от ожидаемого в зависимости от изменения внешних условий. В операционных системах есть понятие сигналов которые передаются между процессами и это может влиять на время ожидания.

Имеет смысл обратить внимание на использование ресурсов системы, они не безграничны. И ситуация когда у вас есть тысячи потоков которые продолжают потреблять ресурсы все же является достаточно тревожным знаком чтобы рекомендовать пересмотр архитектуры приложения.

Вы не опубликовали достаточно информации о характере использования ресурсов вашим приложением, но открытые файлы, подключение к базе данных, сетевые соединения, да и просто память являются исчерпаемыми ресурсами. Если вы интенсивно используете их, то может возникнуть ситуация когда какой-то из ресурсов закончится и ваша система перестанет работать стабильно.

Поэтому, возможно, вам стоит посмотреть на решения типа [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org) или подобные (их слишком много чтобы перечислить) которые позволяют организовать очереди задач. Тогда ресурсы сервера будут использоваться более оптимально и в одну единицу времени будет выполняться только та часть кода которая требует актуального использования ресурсов системы.

В конце-концов 1000 одновременно запущенных процессов в какой-то момент могут вызвать ситуацию когда система тратит все ресурсы на попытку переключения задач, а не их реальное исполнение.

Comment: спасибо, интересная информация)